# ServiceStack RedisMessageQueueClient strange behavior

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, message-queue

My infrastructure:

- Main - ServiceStack self hosted console app. 'Main' sends messages to MQ.
- Background - ServiceStack self hosted console app. 'Background' receives messages from MQ.
- Locally installed Redis

In 'Main' AppHost I configure Redis manager:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(
    new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
```

Then I run this code somewhere in service:

```
using (var client = new RedisMessageQueueClient(TryResolve<IRedisClientsManager>()))
{
    client.Publish(new TestMessage { Value = "From ping" });
}
```

Everything works great and I can get message in my 'Background'. But problem comes when I wrap this code in class:

```
public class MessageQueuePublisher : IMessageQueuePublisher
{
    public void Publish(object message)
    {
        using (var client = new RedisMessageQueueClient(
            EndpointHost.AppHost.TryResolve<IRedisClientsManager>()))
        {
            client.Publish(message);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call MessageQueuePublisher.Publish method from the exactly same place where previous code was executed, it seems like it works correctly (no exceptions are thrown), but my message doesn't reach 'Background'.

Is this OK?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you are actually resolving an instance of IRedisClientsManager in the second code block?

Comment: This wasn't a problem, see my answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. On my 'Background' I expect message with type TestMessage

```
mqService.RegisterHandler<TestMessage>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);
```

But when using *MessageQueuePublisher.Publish* message was of type *object* and went to the  *object* queue and wasn't handled.

So to solve this problem Publish method should be generic:

```
public void Publish<T>(T message)
```

It doesn't change how method is called but code is not so good because if you look at it, it's not clear why generic is used. But at least it works.